# NSInvocation problems

Tags: xcode, nsinvocation

So I am running into some issues when I am trying to load information from a file.

```
myMutableArray=[[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:dataFile]retain];
```

This is the line that gives me the NSinvocation problems

> *** NSInvocation: warning: object 0xf9f500 of class 'myClass' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
>
> *** NSInvocation: warning: object 0xf9f500 of class 'myClass' does not implement doesNotRecognizeSelector: -- abort

I have looked through other questions and other sites to try and find an answer.myClass does inherit from NSObject, and my customer view controller inherits from UIViewController. My customer view controller implements the code above. The save file I am loading from does exist. Not sure what I need to do for this, any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: maybe you could append the archiving code and the definion of myClass (which he is trying to read)

Comment: "myClass does inherit from NSObject" are you sure?

Comment: @interface myClass : NSObject<NSCoding>

Comment: That is from my .h file.

Answer (score 0):

So I had an issue within myClass that I was not encoding something but I was trying to decode it after. I just had to add a line of code and delete my old save file.